# How do I sort a List of dicts by values, without labels?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I'm been thiking of a method for sorting a list without labels and only numbers, like `[{1:2},{3:3},{4:5},{6:10}]` by it's values but I can't come up with a solution. The method should be like this.

`Input:[{1:2},{3:3},{4:5},{6:10}]`

`Output: [{6:10},{4:5},{3:3},{1:2}]`

Can someone help?

Comment: What are the "lables" in the list?

Comment: How would you sort it if the keys were strings instead of numbers (if that's what you mean by "label")?

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular `sort` or `sorted`, with a `key` that uses whatever aggregation of the values you want to sort on (since a dict might have multiple values).  For example:

```
>>> x = [{1:2},{3:3},{4:5},{6:10}]
>>> sorted(x, key=lambda d: -sum(d.values()))
[{6: 10}, {4: 5}, {3: 3}, {1: 2}]
```

Alternatives to `sum` might include:

- `next` (if you're very confident that each dict has exactly one value)
- `statistics.mean` (if they might have varying numbers of values and you want the average)
- `statistics.mode` (if you want the most frequent value in each dict)

etc